# JS/jQuery events/data lost when altering cloned DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pretty new to JS and jQuery and trying to build a plugin for some form controls to dynamically add and remove elements containing inputs and values which should be stored in a database later on.

I am using a list of elements while the first of those elements serves as a template. In preparation to the cloning, a button triggering on click and containing some data is added to remove newly added or already existing elements. Those elements mainly contain input fields with IDs relating to an index.

This issue happens only when altering the HTML which is copied to create a new element in the DOM.

Here is a fiddle displaying the behavior:

```js
$('ul').sortable({
  handle: '.handle',
});

$('<button>remove</button>')
  .appendTo($('li'))
  .click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
  })

const $template = $('ul>li').first().clone(true);

$('<button>another one</button>')
  .appendTo($('#add-btn-holder'))
  .click(function() {
    $clone = $template.clone(true).html(function(i, html) {
      return html.replace(/id-\d-/g, 'id-X-');
    });
    $('ul').append($clone);
  });
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: .4em;
}

[id^="id-X-"] {
  background: #ddd;
}

input {
  height: 3em;
}

.handle {
  cursor: move;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li id="id-0-holder">
    <span class="handle"><b>=</b></span>
    <input id="id-0-field_0" value="val_0_0" />
    <input id="id-0-field_1" value="val_0_1" />
  </li>
  <li id="id-2-holder">
    <span class="handle"><b>=</b></span>
    <input id="id-1-field_0" value="val_1_0" />
    <input id="id-1-field_1" value="val_1_1" />
  </li>
  <li id="id-2-holder">
    <span class="handle"><b>=</b></span>
    <input id="id-2-field_0" value="val_2_0" />
    <input id="id-2-field_1" value="val_2_1" />
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="add-btn-holder">
</div>
```

After adding an new element and altering the html, the event handlers and data will be lost. For simplicity I did not include any data but the click event to remove the new row will be lost.

Commenting out line 17 in the script code (`string#replace`) leaves all events and data intact.

I can store the data values in a temporary variable before altering the html and re-apply them afterwards. I don't know how to deal with events though and hopefully there is an easier solution without temporary variables.

Unfortunately I didn't find anything useful here because most headers sound promising but are solved with a simple `$.clone(true)` or `$.clone(true, true)` (which I am already using).

My real world code is a bit more complex. The remove-button is holding the corresponding to-be-removed item within a data attribute and the query is also build around data, therefore I pretty much have to rely on those values. Unfortunately the classes and IDs may alter why I cannot query with conventional methods.

If this was already asked somewhere else, feel free to guide me there, I wasn't able to find anything useful :(

Comment: When you alter the HTML, it has to be parsed fresh and new DOM created. All the dynamic state is lost. You should modify the DOM elements directly, not recreate the HTML.

Comment: just for clarification (still new to js) meaning I should replace IDs and so on manually e.g. with `attr` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't update the HTML, modify the attributes directly.

When you update the HTML, it's reparsed from scratch and any dynamic modifications to the DOM are lost.

```js
$('ul').sortable({
  handle: '.handle',
});

$('<button>remove</button>')
  .appendTo($('li'))
  .click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
  })

const $template = $('ul>li').first().clone(true);

$('<button>another one</button>')
  .appendTo($('#add-btn-holder'))
  .click(function() {
    $clone = $template.clone(true);
    $clone.find("[id^=id-]").attr('id', function(i, id) {
      return id.replace(/^id-\d+-/, 'id-X-');
    });
    $('ul').append($clone);
  });
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: .4em;
}

[id^="id-X-"] {
  background: #ddd;
}

input {
  height: 3em;
}

.handle {
  cursor: move;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li id="id-0-holder">
    <span class="handle"><b>=</b></span>
    <input id="id-0-field_0" value="val_0_0" />
    <input id="id-0-field_1" value="val_0_1" />
  </li>
  <li id="id-2-holder">
    <span class="handle"><b>=</b></span>
    <input id="id-1-field_0" value="val_1_0" />
    <input id="id-1-field_1" value="val_1_1" />
  </li>
  <li id="id-2-holder">
    <span class="handle"><b>=</b></span>
    <input id="id-2-field_0" value="val_2_0" />
    <input id="id-2-field_1" value="val_2_1" />
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="add-btn-holder">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anything you could do to also replace attributes like `for` and `name` (without explicitely setting them)?
also: curious why this got down voted?

Comment: You can do it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Just `.clone()` the `.last()` `<li>` and increment `#id` and `value` by 1. Delegate the click event by using the `.on()` method. BTW I shortened the `#ids` to save myself some unneeded typing, feel free to use whatever you prefer.

```js
$('ul').sortable({
  handle: '.handle',
});

$('<button>Remove</button>')
  .appendTo('li')
  .on('click', function() {
    if ($('li').length === 1) {
      return;
    } else {
      $(this).closest('li').remove();
    }
  });


let idx;
$('<button>Add</button>')
  .appendTo('.add-box')
  .on('click', function() {

    const $template = $('ul>li').last();
    let prev = Number($template[0].id.split('-').pop());
    idx = prev + 1;
    let $clone = $template.clone(true, true);
    $clone[0].id = `i-${idx}`;
    $clone.find('input').each(function(i) {
      $(this)[0].id = `i-${idx}-f_${i}`;
      $(this).val(`v_${idx}_${i}`);
    });
    $('ul').append($clone);

  });
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: .4em;
}

[id^="id-X-"] {
  background: #ddd;
}

input {
  height: 3em;
}

.handle {
  cursor: move;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="i-0">
    <label class="handle"><b>=</b></label>
    <input id="i-0-f_0" value="v_0_0" />
    <input id="i-0-f_1" value="v_0_1" />
  </li>
  <li id="i-1">
    <label class="handle"><b>=</b></label>
    <input id="i-1-f_0" value="v_1_0" />
    <input id="i-1-f_1" value="v_1_1" />
  </li>
  <li id="i-2">
    <label class="handle"><b>=</b></label>
    <input id="i-2-f_0" value="v_2_0" />
    <input id="i-2-f_1" value="v_2_1" />
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="add-box"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So with some help from your answers I came up with this solution to dynamically handle all attributes matching the regex. thanks.

```js
$('<button>remove</button>')
  .appendTo($('li'));

$('<button>another one</button>')
  .appendTo($('#add-btn-holder'));

// remove-button handler
$('li').on('click', 'button', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
});

const $template = $('li').first().clone(true, true);

// add-button handler
$('#add-btn-holder').on('click', function() {
  $clone = $template.clone(true, true);
  var re = /id-\d-/,
    repl = 'id-X-';
  $clone.find('*').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $($el.get(0).attributes).each(function() {
      $el.prop(this.name, this.value.replace(re, repl));
    })
  });
  $('ul').append($clone);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: .4em;
}

[id^="id-X-"] {
  background: #ddd;
}

input {
  height: 3em;
}

.handle {
  cursor: move;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li id="id-0-holder">
    <input id="id-0-field_0" value="val_0_0" />
    <input id="id-0-field_1" value="val_0_1" />
  </li>
  <li id="id-2-holder">
    <input id="id-1-field_0" value="val_1_0" />
    <input id="id-1-field_1" value="val_1_1" />
  </li>
  <li id="id-2-holder">
    <input id="id-2-field_0" value="val_2_0" />
    <input id="id-2-field_1" value="val_2_1" />
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="add-btn-holder">
</div>
```